# Testing for differences between distributions in the real world

Tags: distributions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, permutation-test

I have a data set that consists of measurements of the size and biomass of zooplankton in the Great Lakes.  The dataset covers 20 years of sampling in each of the lakes.  In essence a net is used to collect the zooplankton which then are classified microscopically by species and measured for length; the biomass is calculated using a species-specific function of length.  This figure, which shows the distribution of biomass by length, is an example of the data for a few years in a few areas of the lakes. The colors represent different functional groups. [image]

Our interpretation of these data is that the size distribution in Lake Superior has remained stable of the years shows, but that there have been substantial changes over time in the other areas depicted.  A reviewer of the paper we submitted presenting these results suggested that we use a "statistical test" (none was specified by the reviewer) to quantify the differences between the size distributions both over time and across lake areas.  We recognize that each year's data is a sample and we don't have any replicates within a year.  Furthermore, each sample is based on enumeration of several thousand individuals and because the determination of length is done with finite precision there are many ties.  I have tried using the two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (I have added some 'jitter' to the data to avoid ties), but every paired comparison results in K-S values that suggest the distributions are different.  I also have tried doing the K-S test with permutations, and running the K-S test on random subsamples of the original distributions but again the results suggest that every comparison is different.  We'd like to satisfy the reviewer's request, so my question is: Is there a test we can use that will enable us to quantify the difference between any two of these size distributions?

Comment: A statistical test does not "quantify differences:" that's a matter for your scientific theory to suggest.  All a test will do is help you assess whether the differences you see in your *samples* may reflect true differences *throughout the lakes and over time,* under the assumption that these samples were obtained in some sort of well-determined random fashion.  This puts the burden back on you to explain what kinds of differences are of scientific importance.

Comment: OK - so I misspoke.  Please tell me then, what test I can use that will help me assess whether the differences I see in the samples may reflect the true differences throughout the lakes and over time. Thanks.

Comment: How where the sampling done? Was the sampling method stable over time? What are these *functional groups*? It looks like some of the change of distributions over time could be due to changing composition of the sample with respect to these functional groups? Is there some interest in investigating that? ... I would maybe start with (modulo answers to above) plotting some aspect of these distributions (means, sd's, skewness, maybe other parameters) with respect to time to see if there is some pattern to the changes.

Comment: Yes, the sampling method, locations, and times of year were stable over time as were the microscopic methods by which the animals were identified and sized.  What I referred to as 'functional groups' are broad taxonomic classes (if you know zooplankton,they include calanoids, cyclopoids, predatory cladocerans, daphnia, non-dapnid cladocerans, and limnocalanus).  Yes, overall size distributions do change because of changes in the taxonomic groups and that is an important aspect of our interpretation. We are just looking for a way to satisfy an anonymous reviewer who wants numbers.

Comment: I would add that the size distribution is important overall because fish that prey on the zooplankton often have preferences for food of a certain size and changes in the zooplankton size structure reflect changes at other trophic levels. The broad patterns are fairly evident.  You don't need statistics (unless you're our reviewer) to conclude that (for example) daphnids in northern Lake Huron declined dramatically between 2002 and 2003.

Comment: Could you post (a link to) the data for us to have a look?